# Populate input field from a dropdown using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
chapter_number | chapter_title |
       1       | Introduction  |
       2       | Number System |


<select type="text" name="chapter_number" class="form-control form-control-line" value="">
    <option selected="option" disabled="selected">Select</option>   
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select

<input type="text" name="chapter_title" id="title" class="form-control"/>
```

> above is my table and next is my code the select option and the input field. I want that when I select '1' automatically the input field will print chapter title 'Introduction' and If I select '2' the input field will became 'Number System'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data from database you need to call ajax on onchange event of select box.

Add "setinput" class to select box

```
<select type="text" name="chapter_number" class="form-control form-control-line setinput" value="">
```

Add below script

```
$('body').on('change','.setinput',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your_base_url/controller_name/your_method',
        type:'POST',
        data:{id:$(this).val()},
        success:function(result){
            $('input[name="chapter_title"]').val(result);
        }
    })

});
```

Controller method would be like below

```
public function your_method(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('database_table_name');
    $this->db->where('chapter_number',$id);
    $result = $this->db->get()->row();
    echo $result->chapter_title;
}
```

I hope, it would be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi sir.. <---A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property 'chapter_title' of non-object---> that is the error..

Comment: the error is in the <--- echo $result->chapter_title; --->